# highlightValue not working in chart with CombinedChartView :: Display marker programmatically is not working :: ChartIssue :: iOS Swift :: DanielGindi

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

**Here is what i am doing!**

```
chart.highlightValue(x: timeStampValue, dataSetIndex: totalCount)
```

==> In the above line,
`timeStampValue` is x axis value which i have set while filling up the array.
`totalCount` is total count of array of data which i am displaying in chart.

**What i need to achieve is**

When chart screen comes up, i need to display marker by default and for that, i am using "highlightValue" method of chart which is not working.

Please let me know the solution to show marker by default programatically.

**NOTE:** I am using marker whose UI is custom which is working fine when i tap manually at point in chart:

```
let marker = CustomMarkerView.viewFromXib()!
marker.chartView = chart
chart.marker = marker
chart.drawMarkers = true
```

Library used : https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Chart Data set :

```
let data = CombinedChartData()
data.lineData = LineChartData(dataSets:[viewModel.lineChartDataSet, viewModel.emptylineChartDataSet])
data.lineData.highlightEnabled = true
viewModel.lineChartDataSet.highlightColor = AssetsColor.highlightedColor.color
        viewModel.lineChartDataSet.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = false
viewModel.lineChartDataSet.highlightLineDashPhase = 2
viewModel.lineChartDataSet.highlightLineDashLengths = [5, 2.5]
```

Comment: can you share your chart dataset code? i think something wrong with your dataSetIndex param

Comment: @aiwiguna, I have updated question with chart dataset code. Please look into that.

Comment: what value is totalCount? you need to share more your code that can be reproducible

Comment: @aiwiguna, Thank you for your interest. I have already mentioned about totalCount in question. 
"totalCount" is total count of array of data which i am displaying in chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chart.highlightValue(x: timeStampValue, dataSetIndex: 0, dataIndex: 0)
```

When i added 1 more parameter which is `dataIndex` as 0 and it worked.

Here, `dataSetIndex` is set to 0 because it is CombinedChartView where i have merged 2 data set.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong value for `dataSetIndex` param

based on your code, the datasets only contains 2 data

```
data.lineData = LineChartData(dataSets:[viewModel.lineChartDataSet, viewModel.emptylineChartDataSet])
```

dataSetIndex is not data count, in linechart dataset represent a line that has many data (x,y), so dataSetIndex is more like which line

so your code should be something like this

```
chart.highlightValue(x: timeStampValue, dataSetIndex: 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. 

I tried with `chart.highlightValue(x: timeStampValue, dataSetIndex: 0)` , but not worked.

Then i tried by adding 1 more parameter which is `dataIndex`. 
`chart.highlightValue(x: timeStampValue, dataSetIndex: 0, dataIndex: 0)`
THIS WORKED.